# PHP clean code $_POST issue

Tags: php, post, cart

$_POST['amount'] does not get the amount of goods and $_POST['itemId'] shows the last item in db but not the one you click at. So all goods are show but form receives just the last one and not the one which is clicked at

```
<div class=cart>
    <b>Cart:</b><br>
    <?php
    if(isset($_POST['add']))
       {?>

    <?=$_POST['amount']?>

       <?php }
  ?>
</div>
<hr>


<?php

class shop
{   
    public function baseConnect()
    {
        $connect = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "test");
        $table = "SELECT * FROM `goods`";
        $result = mysqli_query($connect, $table);

        return $result;
    }
}

$shop = new shop;
$items = $shop->baseConnect();

?>

<form method='post'>
<?php
while ($item = mysqli_fetch_assoc($items))
{?>
    <input type=hidden value='<?=$item['good'];?>' name='itemId'>
    <b><?=$item['good'];?></b><br>
    Price: <?=$item['price'];?>$<br>
    <input type=text name='amount'><br>
    <input type=submit name='add' value='Add to cart'><br>
<?php }
?>
</form>
```

Comment: Move your `<form>` element inside the while loop. Right now when you click submit, you have multiple items with the same `name` attribute.

Comment: This is a very common standard to call class with capital letter: `Shop`

Answer (score 2):

In your code you are creating all of the form input's inside of the same form element and reusing the same name attribute for each element. When you click submit, what is sent to the server is the last instance of those names. Therefore if you add a number to `amount` and click the submit button on an item that is not the last item in your list, you will still receive the values for the last instance of `amount` and `itemId`.

To resolve this, move your `<form method="post" action="">` inside of your while loop (also include the `</form>` tag at the end of the loop).

Change:

```
<form method='post'>
<?php
while ($item = mysqli_fetch_assoc($items))
{?>
    <input type=hidden value='<?=$item['good'];?>' name='itemId'>
    <b><?=$item['good'];?></b><br>
    Price: <?=$item['price'];?>$<br>
    <input type=text name='amount'><br>
    <input type=submit name='add' value='Add to cart'><br>
<?php }
?>
</form>
```

To:

```
<?php while($item = mysqli_fetch_assoc($items)): ?>
    <form method='post' action="">
        <input type="hidden" value='<?php echo $item['good']; ?>' name='itemId'>
        <b><?php echo $item['good']; ?></b><br>
        Price: $<?php echo $item['price']; ?><br>
        <input type="text" name='amount'><br>
        <input type="submit" name='add' value='Add to cart'><br>
    </form>
<?php endwhile; ?>
```

Comment: It would be good to explain in words what's been changed, so pleople (in this case the OP) don't have to find out. _I say the OP because it seems too localized.)